# System.TypeLoadException = "Entry point was not found." ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, exception, mvccontrib-grid

**1. Passing the models from action to View**

```
   public ActionResult Request()
        {
            List<string> buildType = new List<string>();
            BuildRepository bs = new BuildRepository();
            buildType = bs.PopulateBuildType();
            if (buildType.Count() > 0)
            {
                ViewBag.BuildType = new SelectList(buildType);
            }

            List<string> buildMode = new List<string>();
            buildMode.Add("Complete");
            buildMode.Add("Repack");
            ViewBag.BuildMode = new SelectList(buildMode);

            BuildModel bsm = new BuildModel();
            bsm.BuildStatusData();
            return View(bsm);
        }
```

**2. Passing the models from View to Partial View**

```
@{
    BuildModel bm = Model as BuildModel;
}

   <div id="buildstatus">
        @Html.Partial("_BuildStatus", bm)
    </div>
```

**3. Able to get the records for the BuildStatus property (Datasource). But while Grid(3rd property Grid) is not rendered. While checking the column getting the error
"base {System.TypeLoadException} = {"Entry point was not found.":""}"**

```
@{
    BuildModel bm = Model as BuildModel;
}
<div id="buildstatus">
    @{Html.Grid<BuildStatus>("BuildStatusGrid").Datasource(bm.BuildStatus)
      .Column(col =>
          {
              col.Add(c => c.BuildType).HeaderText("Build Type");
              col.Add(c => c.QueuedItems).HeaderText("Queued Time");
              col.Add(c => c.LastStartTime).HeaderText("Last Start Time");
          }).Render(); }
</div>
```

Comment: Am using the ASP.NET MVC 3 Razor.

Comment: do you have the code for the .Grid() extension?

Comment: Sorry, did not see that it was about the conttribbgrid, have no knowledge about that...